# DIY lead acid battery

Tags: lead-acid, battery-chemistry

I need a battery to act as capacitor for a small generator (~7V peak) which does not produce smooth DC. Normal capacitors are unable to deal with ~0.2 second dead time when load is attached, lithium batteries will not be happy in those harsh conditions.

I am unable to find lead acid batteries of 6-8V that fit my setup but have many dead batteries of perfect size. I took one apart and found that the positive plate had turned into dust.

Just for fun, I put two negative plates side by side separated by paper and poured on some dilute sulfuric acid. The battery appeared to work fine and it can produce decent current for its size.

I am unable to find much information online about battery chemistry as to why lead dioxide is used for positive and if only lead from negative plates can work fine as battery.  Should I build my battery without lead dioxide plates? Will it work?

Any way to determine nominal, charge and discharge voltage of a lead acid cell you just made?

Comment: The only time I've seen people attempt this sort of thing is in YT videos from South Asia (Pakistan, mostly, and large truck batteries). You can buy new plates on Indiamart etc. inexpensively. [Here](https://batteryguy.com/kb/knowledge-base/what-is-a-lead-acid-battery/) is an explanation of the manufacturing process of flooded lead-acid batteries.

Comment: I am from Pakistan and they do make batteries in my city too, I can have it made by them but I wanna learn, doubt they will be able to explain the chemistry and dos/don'ts to me @SpehroPefhany

Comment: Be careful in your handling of lead and lead oxide. They are toxic and the effects of repeated exposures are cumulative.

Comment: thanks, I use gloves and avoid powder dust, already scared of lead poisoning @MathKeepsMeBusy

Comment: What is the current expected? What is the commutation frequency you intend to smooth it out, using the battery? Is this generator a single-phase or 3-phase? To be considered: (1) Depending of the current level, a assuming V_peak < 8.4V, you could use 2 Li-ion cells in series. (2) But if you really prefer the L.A. battery type, then 3-cells can reach 7.0V at 100% charged state; gassing may happen for extended use at 7.0V, so distilled water being replenished will be a “must have”. (3) 4-cells would operate in an insufficient voltage level, so this configuration is not good for you.

Comment: Regardless of the number of cells (3 or 4), the Number and Area of lead plates **per cell** will dictate the Ah capacity, but also could promote a lower internal resistance and smoother voltage for the output of your generator.

Comment: Generator outputs different voltages and frequency depending on engine speed and its mood, can I make cells from negative plates only and without positive plates (lead dioxide)? @EJE

Comment: @asim: Reading your posts, I made several comments and suggestions, but heard little. Your question is **about a DIY Lead Acid battery being used as capacitor** but **if not taken care of points I raised, it will not work as intended or simply will not last**. To be used as a capacitor for the generator, the connection between them will be direct. And charging voltages then matters. How you intend to manage that? Yes, plates can be made of pure lead, but needs high charge-discharge cycling  to reach full capacity. Check here: http://wiki.diyfaq.org.uk/index.php/Lead_acid_battery_construction

Comment: Its an old bike, want to upgrade to modern led light but can only find 12v lights so I tried boost converter, light uses 1.2Amps at 12v, original light was a halogen bulb, converter fails, maybe because of undervoltage lockout and protection features, works fine out of the bike with same light, no idea about the frequency but bike battery was 6v @EJE

Comment: I believe you may have mistakenly replied - Lead Acid batteries as capacitor and “old bike& boost converter” doesn’t make sense (for me). Please double-check or clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Planté type battery. Only lead sheets on both sides but needs "forming" by charging and discharging 40 times inverting polarity before being used to store power. Check this site:
https://www.fieldlines.com/index.php?topic=150445.0